# UILabel/Content not appearing in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview

been trying to figure this out for a while. I'm tapping on the CNPPopupController and I'm trying to add a UIScrollView into the UIView.

In the scroll view I will be adding the content, I have tried so far but the content does not seem to be appearing in the UIScrollView. I am not sure what I'm doing wrongly, can anyone please guide me?

```
 //The content view that will house labels and a UIScrollView
    self.contentView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    [self.contentView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    self.contentView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    self.contentView.backgroundColor = self.theme.backgroundColor;
    self.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = self.theme.popupStyle == CNPPopupStyleCentered ? self.theme.cornerRadius : 0.0f;
    [self.maskView addSubview:self.contentView];//The UI ScrollView    
    self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
    //self.scrollView.backgroundColor= self.theme.backgroundColor;
    self.scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(50, 50, 200, 100);

    self.scrollView.layer.cornerRadius = self.theme.popupStyle == CNPPopupStyleCentered ? self.theme.cornerRadius : 0.0f;
    self.scrollView.clipsToBounds = YES; // default is NO, we want to restrict drawing within our scrollview
    self.scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;

    if (self.popupTitle) {
        UILabel *title = [self multilineLabelWithAttributedString:self.popupTitle];
        [self.contentView addSubview:title];
    }
    //Adding items in the UISCrollView
    if (self.contents) {

        for (NSObject *content in self.contents) {
            if ([content isKindOfClass:[NSAttributedString class]]) {
                UILabel *label = [self multilineLabelWithAttributedString:(NSAttributedString *)content];
                [label sizeToFit];
                CGSize scrollViewContentSize = CGSizeMake(self.contentView.frame.size.width, self.contentView.frame.size.height+500);
                [self.scrollView setContentSize:scrollViewContentSize];
                [self.scrollView addSubview:label];
            }
            else if ([content isKindOfClass:[UIImage class]]) {
                UIImageView *imageView = [self centeredImageViewForImage:(UIImage *)content];
                [imageView sizeToFit];
                CGSize scrollViewContentSize = CGSizeMake(self.contentView.frame.size.width, self.contentView.frame.size.height+500);
                [self.scrollView setContentSize:scrollViewContentSize];
                [self.scrollView addSubview:imageView];
                [self.scrollView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:imageView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationLessThanOrEqual toItem:imageView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:1.0 constant:0]];
            }
        }
         [self.contentView addSubview:self.scrollView];
    }
```

Comment: Instead of using sizeToFit you should set a proper frame in both cases and then use sizeToFit if you so choose. Especially since right now, your current contents don't even have origins.

Comment: Proper frame as n CGSizemake or the Frame of the UIScrollview itselfs?

Comment: You already set a frame for your scrollview. I'm talking about the label & image view content.

Comment: Let me give it a try. Thanks!